# Querying Hstore data in ms Access

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, hstore

I am using MS Access to get data from a postgresql source. It's my first time using postgresql and hstore although I have some other experience in T-SQL.
I need to track Hstore key 'Stage_id' value.

My code is as follows;

```
SELECT Log.action_tstamp_stm, Opp.opportunity_code, 
    Log.raw_data, Log.raw_data_old, 
    Log.changed_fields, Log.changed_fields_old
FROM public_ea_crm_opportunity AS Opp 
INNER JOIN logs_logged_actions AS Log 
    ON Opp.id = Log.transaction_id
WHERE Log.table_name="ea_crm_opportunity" AND Log.action="U"
```

I now need to filter that code to extract the values, however when I change the SELECT part to e.g. `Log.raw_data -> 'Stage_id' AS raw_stage`, an error comes up saying

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Log.raw_data -> 'stage_id''

and the `>` character is highlighted in the query when I close that message.  The same error comes up if I try to add `AND Log.raw_data ? 'stage_id'` to the filters, to return rows containing that key.
What am I doing wrong? It seems syntactically correct per my various google searches trying to learn this. Is it that Access can't deal with this data type? If so, is there a way I can convert the whole lot to text then use string functions to extract the key values from that?
(yes I know you may be aghast at the suggestion, but the system this is replacing did exactly that)

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is `->` supposed to mean? Is `'Stage_id'` an alias or a value?

Comment: @Gustav per https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-hstore/, `->` pulls the value of a specific key within an Hstore field. 'Stage_id' is a key alias with a number value e.g. `"Stage_id"=>"3"`

Comment: I see. That you can't with Access SQL, only by using a _pass-through_ query. Such a query you can write in the Access query designer, though Access neither can or will attempt to verify the syntax.